# How to create anchor-positive and anchor-negative pairs from dataset for training the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to apply one-shot learning for face-recognition.
I have several pictures of different people in my dataset directory and want to train my model but the problem is I can't figure out how to provide anchor-positive and anchor-negative pairs from directory of dataset.

I have build a custom convNet model and defined triplet-loss(as described in deeplearning.ai course).

My model

```py
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(384, 384, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())

for t in range(2):
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (1,1), (1,1), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (1,1), (1,1), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

for t in range(3):
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (1,1), (1,1), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (1,1), (1,1), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

for t in range(4):
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (1,1), (1,1), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (1,1), (1,1), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

for t in range(3):
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (1,1), (1,1), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (1,1), (1,1), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D((4,4)))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128))

model.add(layers.Lambda(lambda x: backend.l2_normalize(x,axis=1)))
```

Triplet_loss

```py
def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, alpha = 0.3):
    """
    Implementation of the triplet loss as defined by formula (3)

    Arguments:
    y_pred -- python list containing three objects:
            anchor -- the encodings for the anchor images, of shape (None, 128)
            positive -- the encodings for the positive images, of shape (None, 128)
            negative -- the encodings for the negative images, of shape (None, 128)

    Returns:
    loss -- real number, value of the loss
    """

    anchor, positive, negative = y_pred[0], y_pred[1], y_pred[2]

    # Step 1: Compute the (encoding) distance between the anchor and the positive, you will need to sum over axis=-1
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), axis=-1)
    # Step 2: Compute the (encoding) distance between the anchor and the negative, you will need to sum over axis=-1
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), axis=-1)
    # Step 3: subtract the two previous distances and add alpha.
    basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), alpha)
    # Step 4: Take the maximum of basic_loss and 0.0. Sum over the training examples.
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0))

    return loss
```

Model Compilation

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='triplet_loss',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Please help me in making anchor-positive and anchor-negative pairs for training. I don't have any idea how to handle dataset directory in this regard!

Comment: What is the output of the model?

Comment: I have not trained it yet as I don't know how to handle the dataset in this case.

Comment: Thats fine. What I am asking is what are the tensors that you plan to feed in to the loss module? As in, the inputs of the model are pairs of image-image that match. Therefore, the outputs of the model are embeddings for these images. You get my point?

Comment: A batch of images for anchors, positive images and negative images.

Comment: By positive and negative I mean same person and other person respectively

Comment: @gorjan I am still confused!

Answer (score 0):

Finding triplets to train a Siamese neural network with the triplet loss function can be done in several ways. The original [FaceNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832) paper describes the importance of hard triplets (hard positives, *positives* such that `argmax||f(anchor)-f(positive)||^2` and hard negatives, *negatives* such that `argmin||f(anchor)-f(negative)||^2` where f is the embedding from the neural network.

However, in one of my Siamese networks, I selected (anchor,positive,negative) triplets randomly and it turns out to have a good classification accuracy. So you could try random triplet selection first, as hard-triplet selection is generally computationally expensive and requires a CPU cluster.

I hope you have labelled all the images in the dataset and label should reflect which person that particular image refers to. For an example, if you have 5 images of person A, the labels should look like `(A_1.jpg, A_2.jpg,...A_5.jpg)` or you should have a separate directory for each person. You could select an image from one directory randomly as the anchor, select an image from the same directory as the positive and an image from a different directory as the negative. Bundle this images in triplet format `(anchor,positive,negative)` and repeat the process to create a batch. And there you have a training batch of images.

I just covered the basic procedure of doing it, however, if you're looking for an example code, [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-shot-learning-with-siamese-networks-using-keras-17f34e75bb3d) tutorial may help you to create batches of triplets to a train the network.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments, just modify the triplet loss function that you have in the question in the following way:

```
def triplet_loss(anchor, positive, negative, margin = 0.3):
"""
Implementation of the triplet loss as defined by formula (3)

Arguments:
anchor -- A batch of anchor embedddings (batch_size, embedding size)
positive -- A batch of positive embedddings (batch_size, embedding size)
negative -- A batch of negative embedddings (batch_size, embedding size)
margin -- The contrastive margin

Returns:
loss -- real number, value of the loss
"""

# Step 1: Compute the (encoding) distance between the anchor and the positive, you will need to sum over axis=-1
pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), axis=-1)
# Step 2: Compute the (encoding) distance between the anchor and the negative, you will need to sum over axis=-1
neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), axis=-1)
# Step 3: subtract the two previous distances and add alpha.
basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), margin)
# Step 4: Take the maximum of basic_loss and 0.0. Sum over the training examples.
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0))

return loss
```

The real issue with computing the triplet loss is to come up with the triplets, or mine them. However, that is already done for as you mentioned in the comments discussion.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is wrong. We do not calculate `pos_dist`, `neg_dist` and `loss` with mere `anchor`, `positive` and `negative` triplets. We input the triplets to the Siamese network and find the "embeddings" which is `y_pred` in the OP. What OP asks is that how to find these triplets and bundle them into a batch, so basically the code of doing this.

Comment: Go through the comment discussion. If op has a directory of images which are already batched together in triplets, then there isn't anything to mine. On the other hand, if he has a directory of images together with labels, then you are right.